# Correct usage of PublishSubject with CocoaAsyncSocket

Tags: swift, observable, rx-swift, cocoaasyncsocket

I'm creating simple messaging app based on CocoaAsyncSocket and STOMP protocol. So I created main class, which use `PublishSubject`, so the subscribers can observe incoming STOMP frames, something like this:

```
class StompStream: NSObject {
//MARK: - Public
     var inputFrame = PublishSubject<StompFrame>()

//MARK: - Private
    fileprivate var socket: GCDAsyncSocket!
    ...
    ...
    fileprivate func parse(withData data: Data) {
        let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        do {
            let frame = try StompFrame(text: string)
            self.inputFrame.on(.next(frame))
        } catch {
            self.inputFrame.on(.error(error))
        }
     }
 }
//MARK: - GCDAsyncSocketDelegate methods
extension StompStream: GCDAsyncSocketDelegate {
    ...
    ...
    func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didRead data: Data, withTag tag: Int) {
        self.parse(withData: data)
    }
}
```

So, other who want to read `inputFrame`, just do:

```
fileprivate func subscribeToEvents() {
    self.stompStream.inputFrame
        .observeOn(SerialDispatchQueueScheduler(queue: Queues().stompQueue, internalSerialQueueName: "stomp"))
        .subscribe( onNext: { inputFrame in
            //do some stuff
        }).addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
}
```

I'm very new to RxSwift, and I read, that it's better to use `Observable<StompFrame>`, if we want to just read the events, but with PublishSubject I can init it like this - `PublishSubject<StompFrame>()`, and with `Observable<StompFrame>` I couldn't understand how to do such thing, without creating some `func`, where I will return `Observable.create { }`, so every time if somebody will want to receive events, it will create another `Observable<StompFrame>`, but with `PublishSubject` it's only one.
Thanks for any help to explaining me this Rx stuff :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the code is bridging from imperative to reactive world, here it makes sense to use a `PublishSubject` **under the hood**.

A good practice is to make this subject private and only expose the `Observable` to outside users.

```
class StompStream: NSObject {
    var inputFrame: Observable<StompFrame> { 
        return inputFrameSubject.asObservable() 
    }

    private let inputFrameSubject = PublishSubject<StompFrame>()

    // ...
}
```

When in doubt about using a subject or not, I always refer to [this post](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx). Though written for C#, it is a great reference for this topic.